# Windows Phone Mango background transfer service policy

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, policy, background-transfer

While going through a WP7.5 background transfer service policy, one can read the following:

> The background transfer service does not run on non-simultaneous voice
>   and data networks including the following: 2G, EDGE, Standard GPRS

So if a client's only connection to the internet is EDGE, my application won't be able to upload files with background transfer services at all?

Comment: Looks like that's the case. And it makes sense too -- you don't want a user to not recieve/ answer phone calls b/c some app is hogging all the resources. Likewise, you don't want to start a transfer you can't finish because the user uses the phone.

Comment: You might be able to queue a future upload that will start when a better connection is available, but I haven't personally tried this.

Comment: It sometimes refuses to work on 4G too. BTS is only useful in few cases. And not reliable, as you can implement it without knowing some network will prevent the download/upload to start, making a whole application useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct, unfortunately it is completely possible that BTS will not work for some of your users.

Consider using the network information APIs to warn users when they're not on WiFi or fast enough connections.

You could even try and get fancy, recording the network information every time the app starts up - and after a few consecutive EDGE-style connections, warn them.

Comment: Jeff, you mean I can't just look-up if the current connection is EDGE-based? I need to do a speed-based evaluation or something? (Sorry for a question in comments)

Comment: You can look it up - look at the APIs such as those talked about here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2011/07/28/windows-phone-7-checking-network-connections-before-downloading.aspx